# minikube won't start after a reboot

Tags: minikube, kubelet

After rebooting Ubuntu 22 minikube will not start.  It shows this error message:

```
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
...
Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
    timed out waiting for the condition

This error is likely caused by:
    - The kubelet is not running
    - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)
```

I never installed kubelet on this machine and minikube was running before the reboot.  The  [minikube install docs](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/) don't say anything about kubelet.

What could cause minikube to not start after rebooting?

Answer (score 0):

Another reboot solved this problem.  (Did Microsoft write minikube?)